# screenshot of all Views in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that consist of List of ScrollViews. I want to make a screenshot from all of the Scrollviews after the first load of the ViewPager.

After ViewPager is created, i am going through the Views and creating bitmaps, but i get a screenshot only for the first pages that are loaded offscreen. 
If i use the command:

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(totalPages);
```

than I am able to get all of the screenshots. However this approach is memory consuming and my app crashes with outOfMemory when the ViewPager consists of a lot of pages.

Is there a way to create screenshot of all the views even the ones that are not preloaded - offScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set `offScreenPageLimit(totalPages)`, `ViewPager` will initially only load 1 more page other than you see. That means other pages will not be even created until you swipe there. That also means you cannot take screenshot of a screen/layout that is not created/inflated yet. And yes, it is not a good practice memorywise to set offscreen page limit to a number that `ViewPager` loads all pages at start.

**Answer:** No, if you mind your memory consumption. Otherwise, yes.